# Access host port on localhost from guest OS in VirtualBox in windows

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox

Hello I have a server with port 2030 open and I want to open this in VirtualBox in a Windows 7 guest with the address

```
localhost:2030
```

Not with:

```
10.0.2.2:2030
```

Can I solve this with VirtualBox port forwarding?

Comment: You could edit the `hosts` file on the Win7 machine to change the mapping of `localhost`. This might have unexpected consequences though.